# Writing a method that accesses the system?

Tags: java, methods, processbuilder

I am trying to write a java method system("ls") that accepts a string and then can output something from the system(terminal). When i run my current program it works and outputs src/bin. But when i add "ls -l" the program terminates and i get no output. I'm clueless and how to fix this. Here is my code.

```
public class getSystemInfo
{
   public static void main(String args [])
   {
       system("ls -l");
   }

public static void main(String args [])
{
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s = "ls -l";
    StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(s,"-,:");
    while(tok.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        array.add(tok.nextToken());
    }


    try
    {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder(array).redirectErrorStream(true).start();
        Scanner c = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
        while(c.hasNext())
        {
            println(c.nextLine());
        }
        c.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but don't use java for something like this which you can do by one-liners in scripting languages

Comment: i know that but its an assignment in school to learn how to make a method that will do this. I know other programming languages have a method like this but java does not

Comment: You need to handle the streams.Study this http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1

Comment: i read it but i'm confused on how I read the string using deilimiters and add it to an arraylist

Comment: It would help to print something from the catch, like System.out.println(e) . You may be getting exceptions and silently swallowing them.

Comment: @user3242607:Sorry I did not understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

you can [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) the command on [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) (for e.g. `"-"`) and then create proper params for your command.  e.g.

```
private static void system(String cmd) throws IOException {
        List<String> params = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] chunks = cmd.split("-");
        params.add(chunks[0].trim());

        for (int i = 1; i < chunks.length; i++) {
            params.add("-"+chunks[i].trim());
        }

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder (params);
        Process p = pb.start();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println((sc.nextLine()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in the right direction. Try tokenizing on the space to separate the command name and the parameters, like this:

```
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(s," ,:");
```

Answer (score 0):

i found out that processBuilder doesn't accept * characters so i needed to add sh -c in front of my array.

```
public static void main(String args [])
{
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
String s = "ls -l";
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(s,"-,:");
while(tok.hasMoreTokens())
{
    array.add("sh");
    array.add("-c");
    array.add(tok.nextToken());
}
```